# Не принимают обоснованную тревогу

Tags: поддержка, тревоги

На этот вопрос отправил тревогу непонятна суть вопроса: [Xml parsing from URL insert into database in android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/845210/xml-parsing-from-url-insert-into-database-in-android) 
Но она до сих пор в ожидании. Хотя после этого уже одобрили другую. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: А чего вы ожидали? Чтобы вопрос сразу закрыли?

Comment: чтобы тревогу приняли как полезную

Comment: Её даже не отклонили, а просто никто пока не добрался? Нужно же понимать, что модерацией занимаются живые люди.

Comment: одобрили спс...

Comment: @vp_arth живые?

Comment: @alexolut, вероятнее всего =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Причина в том, что в очереди голосов на закрытие - 488 вопросов (на текущий момент). Набирайте репутацию и принимайте участие в разгребании этой очереди раз уж вам настолько небезразлично качество сайта :-)

Другая же тревога могла быть уже одобрена по разным причинам. Но скорее всего пять участников с правом голосовать за закрытие вопроса случайно этот самый вопрос увидели и решили закрыть.

PS и не надо на каждую непроверенную тревогу создавать вопрос на Мете! Тот вопрос, который вы заметили, ничем не хуже остальных 487 вопросов из очереди на закрытие.